# I get the following error when I try to include Combinatorica Package in Mathematica 8

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, kernel, combinatorics

I typed the following command in my terminal(Ubuntu 12.04) :

```
In[41]:= << Combinatorica`;

General::compat: 
   Combinatorica Graph and Permutations functionality has been superseded by
   preloaded functionaliy. The package now being loaded may conflict with
   this. Please see the Compatibility Guide for details.
```

Please help.

Comment: have  you read the docs referenced by the error message?

Comment: sorry, I'm new to mathematica. I don't understand what you were trying to explain. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: I have the same problem, but I am trying to use the function ChromaticNumber ... I cannot find that function in the compatibility guide too. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: you should probably see the following links:

[1] http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/Combinatorica/ref/ChromaticNumber.html

[2] http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/Combinatorica/ref/MinimumVertexColoring.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer lies here:

http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/Compatibility/tutorial/Combinatorica.html